# Example.com having the same thing for every page

Tags: html, web

I was just example.com have the same thing for every page, even if it is ridiculous such as example.com/2u3094u2p3kj2lk4j? It doesn't seem to be making a redirect. If that isn't the case, what is it? What is the code behind it? Why is the code the same for everypage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using htaccess. Create a file called ".htaccess", and paste this code in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

This will redirect all traffic to "index.html"

Matt

Answer (score 0):

If you had inspected the NET-tab in Firebug, or any other console, you'd see that that link (or any other link) will return a 404, and redirect to example.com but keep the "page" in the URL. It's a simple setup, made to make anything you want to write in that URL-string go to the main domain.